# Displaying local images using img tag after upgrading cordova-file in Android, "cdvfile://" deprecation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Cordova app that I'm upgrading to target Android 33. In the process, I've updated a number of Cordova plugins, including `cordova-plugin-file` to version 8.0.1-dev.

This app allows a person to take photos, which saves the photo to the app's persistent storage via cordova-file's tools (which still works, and can verify the image is stored correctly via `adb`), and displays them (no longer works). My code for displaying the images is:

```
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/my_image.jpg">
```

The image no longer displays on the device and I get this error in the JavaScript console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I've read [this Github issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1053) that the cdvfile protocol is no longer supported. However, I'm really struggling to see what the better way is now to go about displaying images in the DOM.

I can get the image path by using `cordova.file.dataDirectory + files/my_image.jpg`, which produces something like `file:///data/user/0/com.app.name/files/files/my_image.jpg`. When I put that in as the image source (as in `<img src="file:///data/user/0/com.app.name/files/files/my_image.jpg">`), I then get this error in the JavaScript console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/com.app.name/files/files/my_image.jpg
```

If `cdvfile://...` no longer works in the DOM, what is the suggested alternative for loading local files?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I replaced all my paths that started with `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/` with `https://localhost/__cdvfile_persistent__/` and it's now working.